# Is there a way to save my workspaces through reset/shutdown?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I have several workspaces that have several terminals open in each one. I need to reboot my system, but I don't want to have to recreate each workspace after reboot.

Is there a way to save the state of each workspace, so after reboot all terminals reopen in the same working directory they were before, and preferably with the command history as well?

Answer (score 1):

If reset/shutdown isn't the important part of it, you could hibernate the machine, suspending the state to the disk.

That way you are able to power off the computer without losing your state.

Another way would be to make use of tmux and scripts to have the state start automatically, then you could use your Desktop Environment to keep track of the windows and restore them (XFCE supports this pretty nicely), keeping some of your state (but not all).